# how do i get the uniq value for this hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I want to get the uniq region and filtered with "status = stopped".
without using any loop. Is it possible?

**hash:**

```
{"a123" => {"status"=>"stopped", "region"=>"US-EAST"},
 "b123" => {"status"=>"stopped", "region"=>"US-EAST"},
 "c123" => {"status"=>"stopped", "region"=>"US-WEST"},
 "d123" => {"status"=>"running", "region"=>"US-WEST"},
 "e123" => {"status"=>"running", "region"=>"US-NORTH"}}
```

my code for filtering status:

```
hash.select{ |k, v| v["status"] == "stopped" }.values

#=> [{"status"=>"stopped", "region"=>"US-EAST"},
     {"status"=>"stopped", "region"=>"US-EAST"},
     {"status"=>"stopped", "region"=>"US-WEST"}]
```

I dont know what's next to do and I want the output to be :

```
#=> {"US-EAST", "US-WEST"}
```

I'm a noob in ruby and hash. Please help ^_^

Comment: `{"US-EAST", "US-WEST"}` is not valid ruby

Comment: sorry ["US-EAST", "US-WEST"] i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash.map {|_,v| v['region'] if v['status'] == 'stopped'}.compact.uniq
# => ["US-EAST", "US-WEST"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 hash.select{ |k,v| v["status"] == "stopped" }.values.map { |e| e["region"] }.uniq
=> ["US-EAST", "US-WEST"]

# use `map` method to put region to an array
hash.select{ |k,v| v["status"] == "stopped" }.values.map { |e| e["region"] }
=> ["US-EAST", "US-EAST", "US-WEST"]

#then use the `uniq` method remove repeated.
["US-EAST", "US-EAST", "US-WEST"].uniq
=> ["US-EAST", "US-WEST"]

hash.select{ |k,v| v["status"] == "stopped" }.values.map{ |e| {"region" => e["region"]}}.uniq
=> [{"region"=>"US-EAST"}, {"region"=>"US-WEST"}]
```

Comment: Thank you ^_^. it is now working. 1 more question please, what if I want the result with key ["region" => "US-EAST", "region" => "US-WEST"]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
require 'set'

hash.each_with_object(Set.new) do |(_,h),s|
  s << h["region"] if h["status"]=="stopped"
end.to_a
  #=> ["US-EAST", "US-WEST"]
```

Comment: I already thought about this (using loop), but I want is a one line code ^_^ anyways THANK YOU for the answer.